# Applying a function to every component of a list of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I tried to find Max or Min to lists of lists, with Map with Apply ... but the only way has been Module ...   maybe someone can show us a direct more efficient way

this is the source of data:

```
maxtest ={{7, 2, 5}, {7, 8, 1}, {20, 1, 19}, {8, 23, 15}, {26, 27, 1}, {13, 17,
   4}, {3, 25, 22}, {28, 4, 24}, {25, 14, 11}, {24, 28, 4}, {25, 0, 
  25}, {11, 7, 4}, {28, 20, 8}, {6, 25, 19}, {34, 12, 22}, {25, 9, 
  16}, {6, 19, 13}, {10, 15, 5}, {7, 7, 0}, {23, 28, 5}}
```

and this is the weak solution I wrote

```
maxlist[lst_] := Module[{dim, i},
  dim = Dimensions[lst[[2]]][[1]];
  resp = Table[0, dim];
  For[i = 1, i <= dim, i++,
   resp[[i]] = Max[lst[[All, i]]]];
  Return [resp]
  ]
```

giving me

```
In[17]:= maxlist[maxtest]

Out[17]= {34, 28, 25}
```

thanks for help!

Comment: Try e.g. `{Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ maxtest`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but this gives me a list of lists where each term has tha min and the max of every term. I pretend to have the min of all list[[1]] the min of all[2]]   and so on for any dimension of the elements

Comment: `Transpose[MinMax /@ Transpose@maxtest]`

Comment: Is this what you want? `mins = Min /@ maxtest;
maxs = Max /@ maxtest`

Comment: LouisB - Good Thanks this is stright to the solution   I will study how you arrive to this fast solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
MapThread[Min, maxtest]
MapThread[Max, maxtest]
```

> {3, 0, 0}
>
> {34, 28, 25}

And here are two nice undocumented functions that do the same job very efficiently:

```
Random`Private`MapThreadMin[maxtest]
Random`Private`MapThreadMax[maxtest]
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik Schumacher, that's it,   ok it's a function   in the dark ,   well in M11.2 I had to write the procedural way.

Comment: Sorry I look first your undocumented answer,   MapThread[f,list] is perfect. Vielen Danke

Comment: Bitte sehr! Gern geschehen. =D

Answer (score 3):

```
minMax = Thread @* MapThread[MinMax @* List];

minMax @ maxtest
```

> ```
> {{3, 0, 0}, {34, 28, 25}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked it and of course works. I never used @* together, I would study how it works and try to get profit for next opportunity

Answer (score 2):

```
m =
  {{7, 2, 5}, {7, 8, 1}, {20, 1, 19}, {8, 23, 15}, {26, 27, 1}, 
  {13, 17, 4}, {3, 25, 22}, {28, 4, 24}, {25, 14, 11}, {24, 28, 4}, 
  {25, 0, 25}, {11, 7, 4}, {28, 20, 8}, {6, 25, 19}, {34, 12, 22}, 
  {25, 9, 16}, {6, 19, 13}, {10, 15, 5}, {7, 7, 0}, {23, 28, 5}};
```

Using `ArrayReduce` (new in 12.2)

```
ArrayReduce[#, m, 1] & /@ {Min, Max, MinMax}
```

{{3, 0, 0}, {34, 28, 25}, {{3, 34}, {0, 28}, {0, 25}}}

To apply a function to matrix rows we use `2` as last parameter

```
ArrayReduce[Min, list, 2]
```

{2, 1, 1, 8, 1, 4, 3, 4, 11, 4, 0, 4, 8, 6, 12, 9, 6, 5, 0, 5}

Answer (score 2):

```
    m =
      {{7, 2, 5}, {7, 8, 1}, {20, 1, 19}, {8, 23, 15}, {26, 27, 1}, 
      {13, 17, 4}, {3, 25, 22}, {28, 4, 24}, {25, 14, 11}, {24, 28, 4}, 
      {25, 0, 25}, {11, 7, 4}, {28, 20, 8}, {6, 25, 19}, {34, 12, 22}, 
      {25, 9, 16}, {6, 19, 13}, {10, 15, 5}, {7, 7, 0}, {23, 28, 5}}
```

---

Using `Thread`:

```
minMax = Thread[MinMax /@ Thread@#] &;

minMax@m

(*{{3, 0, 0}, {34, 28, 25}}*)
```

To apply a function to matrix rows, we proceed as follows:

```
Thread[Min /@ m] === ArrayReduce[Min, m, 2]

(*True*)
```